# error "CARES_SIZEOF_LONG & CARES_SIZEOF_ARES_SOCKLEN_T definition is missing!"

Tags: grpc, qnx

I am trying to cross compile gRPC with QNX7 for ARM.
I am using cmake for c++.

I am using following command:

I am getting following error message while compiling

```
[ 42%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/grpc_unsecure.dir/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_ev_driver_libuv.cc.o
[ 42%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/grpc_unsecure.dir/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_ev_driver_posix.cc.o
In file included from /usr/include/ares.h:23:0,
                 from /local/mnt/workspace/grpc/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_ev_driver_posix.cc:23:
/usr/include/ares_rules.h:72:4: error: #error "CARES_SIZEOF_LONG definition is missing!"
 #  error "CARES_SIZEOF_LONG definition is missing!"
    ^
/usr/include/ares_rules.h:82:4: error: #error "CARES_SIZEOF_ARES_SOCKLEN_T definition is missing!"
 #  error "CARES_SIZEOF_ARES_SOCKLEN_T definition is missing!"
    ^
```

Does anybody face this issue before? How I can solve this?

Comment: It looks like it's bringing in headers from "/usr/include", which is usually part of the host system (ie. not the cross target).   This can happen when badly written dependency resolution cmake fragments have hardcoded search paths -- or when they call out to tools like pkg-config without the appropriate environment variables set.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I tried to delete the cares library from system, so that it should use the cross compiler cares library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to delete the cares library which was installed in my ubuntu system, so that it should use the cross compiler cares library.

Comment: Did this fix the problem?

Comment: Yes @apolcyn.It fixed the problem.